# Cannot pass id variable in div and data-target in html

Tags: html

I want to create a bunch of button for the Model.Info since the Info is pretty large string. Currently, I'm stuck at variable passing in data-target and div id. I cannot type in $"num{i}" to get the dynamic id and pass the information one by one to the relative button.

Anybody knows how to fix it?

```
for(int i = 0; i < @Model.Count; i++)
{
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#num0">
  Info
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="num0">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                  @Model[i].Info
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: What else are you using beside html? Where does the @Model comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Oh. It's fixed by @ variable;

```
var curId = "#num" + i;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=@curId>
```